# How to clear the variable with library type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I use leaflet with typescript. I want to clear the leafletMap variable, but can't assign it to null.

[can't assign null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08np7.png)

When I give make the leafletMap type to compound types with null. The library function throws error.

[compound types with null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHtUu.png)

Is there any way to clear leafletMap variable value?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please include a [mcve] as [formatted code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918), not images. Take a look at the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: You're saying that the variable is of type `L.Map` only so you can't assign it to null. You need to declare it as `L.Map|null` to allow assigning to null and that also means you need to check if it's null before using it since there's a chance you made it null

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Leaflet, but since you're declaring that your `leafletMap` variable might be null you probably just need to add some checks before passing it to a function that requires it to be not null.

Something like:

```
addLine() {
    if (!leafletMap) {
        return;
    }
    // Do sth with leafletMap if it's not null
}
```